# Adding two numbers becomes concatenating two numbers, but the result is a number value? Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

I have three inputs that need to be calculated.  I used the .val()  method in jQuery to get the value of the input and calculate them with following:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
 $("#calculate").click(function(){
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="$"+($("#einc").val()+$("#iinc").val()-$("#slint").val());
   $("#result").css("display","inline");
});
```

The first two inputs don't add up, they concatenate; i.e. 5+5=55.
However, the subtraction works fine. So if my first two inputs are 10 and 10 and my last input is 5, it will give me 1010-5=1005.

My expected answer should be 10+10-5=5.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: input values return strings ..."10"+"10"  will be "1010"

Comment: Pretty sure the expected answer should be 15 in that second-to-last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Number($("#your_input_field_id").val());
```

jQuery val() returns string.

Comment: This works!!! Magicallllllly

Answer (score 2):

Because .val() returns string and `+` also act as the string concatenation operator.

You can convert the string value to a numeric one using `parseInt()/parseFloat()/unary operator`

```
$("#result").html("$" + (+$("#einc").val() + (+$("#iinc").val()) - $("#slint").val()));
```

Comment: @Ming Huang pick this answer :)

Comment: parseFloat() works fine with my project; what is the major difference between using parseFloat() and Number()?  they all return decimal number values.